# How to filter Azure AD Audit by Actor using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am desperately looking for a way to filter the AD audit log that Azure provides via Azure AD Graph API by the user that triggered the event (or an actor as MS calls it).

At the moment I am using the following endpoint to request the audit log:

`https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/activities/audit?api-version=beta&$filter=actor eq 'the actors username'`

Apart from that, I have tried the following filter strings:

- `actor/userPrincipleName eq 'the actors username'`
- `actor/userprinciplename eq 'the actors username'`
- `actor/id eq 'the actors id'`

However, I always end up with an error like this:

> Could not find a property named `'userPrincipleName'` on type
>   `'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.DataService.PublicApi.Model.Reporting.AuditLog.ActorEntity'`.

Since it is possible to filter by UAP in the AuditLogs in Azure Portal I was assuming this should be possible via the API as well.

It would be great if somebody could point me in the right direction since I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You are querying the Azure AD Graph API (graph.windows.net), which is in frozen state with no future works (described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog)). Even using some beat features of it, non or partially documented. And ask why it isn't working? I suggest that you take a look at [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/directoryaudit), rebuild what you need using the `Microsoft Graph` and then place your question if you face challenges.

Comment: Hi @astaykov! Thanks for your reply and sorry for any confusion caused. The reason why we are using the frozen Azure AD Graph API is, because we need it to manage AD B2C users. According to our consultant this is (at least at the moment) not possible using the Windows Graph.

Comment: That is correct, you need to use AAD Graph to manage user accounts in AAD B2C at the moment. Keep in mind that this _doesn't_ mean you can't use **Microsoft Graph** as well (note: there isn't a "Windows Graph").